# Haskell "Could not find module ---" Quipper

Tags: haskell, module, quantum-computing

I am extremely new to haskell and I have been searching all over the web but I haven't been able to solve my problem. I downloaded the Quipper [package](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/quipper/) but I have not been able to get haskell to recognize where all of the modules and files are and how to properly link everything.

I have downloaded all of the files and programs and installed them properly, I just dont know how to get haskell to recognize the quipper libraries and templates. Evey time I try:

`:load And_gate.hs` or some other file.

I get:

`Could not find module "Quipper"` or its respective modules it requires.

I don't think it is an error or anything, I think it is just my lack of knowledge on how haskell works.

I'm using windows 7.

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what your install process was, could you clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

So I emailed Peter Selinger, one of the professors who created Quipper.

The only thing I need to do extra was inside MSYS:

`ghci -iC:/quipper -iC:/quipper/quipper`

This complies everything correctly and the files run properly.

Here is his email to me:

> Dear -----,
>
> thanks for writing. Let me see if I can help.
>
> Are you following the instructions in the README file? Under "Building
>   the various algorithms and programs", the instruction is to run
>   "make". This would build all of the tests in the "tests" directory
>   automatically.
>
> Next, to compile a Quipper program, you should use the "quipper"
>   script that is located in quipper/scripts. It works just like "ghc",
>   except that it automatically includes the correct directories for
>   Quipper's files in the search path. On Windows, you would be using
>   "quipper.bat".
>
> Quipper is not really meant to be run interactively, i.e., from ghci.
>   However, if you do need to run Quipper interactively, I recommend
>   using the "quipperi" script, also in quipper/scripts. This too would
>   set the load paths correctly. In Windows, use "quipperi.bat".
>
> Finally, if you need to include Quipper stuff from ghci, but for some
>   reason can't or don't want to use the quipperi script, you need to
>   specify those directories with the "-i" option, for example
>
> ghci -iC:/quipper -iC:/quipper/quipper
>
> It could be that in Windows, you need to use "\" instead of "/", but I
>   am not sure if this is necessary.
>
> I hope this helps, -- Peter

When compiling and exe with ghc just make sure you include the commands:

`-iC:/quipper -iC:/quipper/quipper`.

If you use the quipper script as suggested by Professor Selinger, inside of MSYS do the following:

Navigate to the folder in which all of the Quipper files are held, this was my case:

`cd C:/quipper/quipper/scripts`

Then type `quipper` and your file's location in MSYS to compile an exe like so:

`quipper C:/quipper/tests/And_gate.hs`

The file will compile and should print updates like so:

> `[1 of 22] Compiling Libraries.Typeable (......`
>
> `[2 of 22] Compiling Libraries.Tuple (......`

and so on.

The exe (in this case `And_gate.exe`) will be inside the folder it was compiled from (`C:/quipper/tests`). You'll need to move it to a folder that contains the acroread.bat which comes in `quipper/scripts` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this code isn't packaged as a standard Haskell package. It if were, installing it would be fairly simple. As it is, the instructions in the README file look awful (especially under Windows, where it looks like you need MSYS to run the makefile).

Your problem *might* be as simple as telling GHCi which folder to look in to find the files; you can do that using the `:cd` command. Since you're on Windows, I'd suggest trying WinGHCi, which should allow you to browse to the right folder using the GUI.

If it isn't that simple... really, as a Haskell beginner, you're probably going to struggle to get this working. The documentation looks pretty minimal.

Comment: That is actually slightly helpful, I `:cd C:/quipper/quipper` and now it says it can not find `Libraries.Auxiliary` which is in `C:/quipper/Libraries` a higher folder. So looks like I am going to have to talk directly the makers of Quipper, or figure out how to build an installable package myself.

But thanks for the answer, I won't have to be running around in circles looking for a solution.

Comment: I found the answer, just needed: 

`ghci -iC:/quipper -iC:/quipper/quipper` inside MSYS

Asking him if I can post his email to stack overflow for anyone else to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you red both `README` and `INSTALLING.windows` and did everything as well, then you should add a path to Quipper's script folder to environment variable. Here is the path:

```
quipper-*/quipper/scripts/
```

where `quipper-*` is a `<distribution name>-<version>`.

There are two important scripts in that folder. The first one is `quipper.bat` which runs a `ghc` compiler to run Quipper's modules. The second one is `quipperi.bat` which is a `ghci` analogue for Quipper.

Now, when you added a path to variable, you can run `And_gate.hs` in Quipper's interpreter as follows:

```
quipperi And_gate.hs
```